# awk - Does gawk have anything like the __LINE__ macro?

Tags: awk, gawk

I'm using gawk and I want to know if it's possible to output the line of the script. I checked the gawk's manual and found information on [auto-set variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html#Auto_002dset) but anything like `__LINE__` isn't listed. Thanks

To clarify here I mean the actual line of the awk script not what input I'm reading. So if I do `cat foo | script.awk` I am looking for the line number in script.awk. Basically I'd like to show the line number that an error occurred on in my script, if possible.

Comment: The awk-interpreter is pretty good at telling you on what line an error occured, e.g. `awk: avg.awk:20:  ^ syntax error`. What would you use this for?

Comment: @Fredrik I'm not concerned about those errors, I mean errors in my script where I have to do `print "exiting on error!"; exit 1;`

Comment: Change the exit code to something unique then that allows you to easily identify that line by searching for e.g. `exit 42`. Shell interprets every exit code greater than 0 to be a failure so all your `&&` and `||`, `$?` will work as expected.

Comment: Have you tried dgawk, the integrated debugger in GNU awk 4.x?

Comment: @Fredrik Thanks but I'm looking for something that can get the line numbers automatically. I have a lot of places where the program may terminate due to an error.

Comment: @Code I haven't tried that. I'm looking for something that will show for the user as well. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not. Let us know if you'd like suggestions for workarounds, e.g. creating a new awk script from the original awk script:

```
$ cat tst.sh
tmp="/usr/tmp/tmp.awk"
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; exit' 0
> "$tmp"
chmod oug+x "$tmp"

awk '{ sub(/__LINE__/,NR); print }' <<! > "$tmp" && "$tmp"
awk 'BEGIN {
    print "this is line", __LINE__
    print "this is line", __LINE__
    print "this is line", __LINE__
}'
!
$ ./tst.sh
this is line 2
this is line 3
this is line 4
```

Comment: Unfortunately this looks to be the right answer. Interesting workaround!